# Configuring postfix to deliver local intra-user mail, and remote email to specific addresses

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server

I am trying to configure a Postfix server to:

- Deliver mail from local users to both other local users and remote addresses; and
- Accept incoming mail only for some (explicitly listed) addresses of my domain (regardless of what the local users are).

The hostname of the machine is `mydomain.con` and I have currently configured postfix as follows:

- `myhostname = localhost`
- `mydestination = localhost` (this prevents mails for localuser@mydomain.com to be accepted)
- `virtual_alias_domains = mydomain.com`
- `virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual`, where `/etc/postfix/virtual` maps email addresses from mydomain.com to local users, e.g.:

```
john.smith@mydomain.com localuser@localhost
```

This setup works correctly for incoming mail sent to `john.smith@mydomain.com` (it is delivered to user `localuser`). However, it doesn't allow local users to send mail to other local users.
For example, an email sent to user `alice` (e.g., using `mail alice`) is sent to `alice@mydomain.com`, which is then matched (unsuccessfully) against the virtual alias file, and the delivery ultimately fails.

Can somebody advise me? Do I need to change the hostname of the machine to a private one and set `myhostname` accordingly? If so, how can I prevent outside clients from delivering mail to `localuser@myhostname`?

On somewhat related note: what part of the Postfix configuration (if any) is currently preventing it from accepting mail for `localuser@localhost` from a foreign SMTP client? (notice that rejecting mail addressed to `localuser@localhost` is the desired behavior)

Thank you!

Comment: mail client uses dns mx record and localhost is not a domain, local mail users are internal to the mail mailserver, when you write an email from user1@domain.com to user2@domain.com the delivery is locally, you could try checking the postfix logs

Comment: @c4f4t0r, I know about MX records and clearly no legitimate mail client would attempt to deliver mail for localuser@localhost to my server. Yet, nothing prevents a malicious client from directly connecting to the server's address on port 25 and try to deliver mail addressed to localuser@localhost. I'm just asking what part of the default postfix configuration (if any) is responsible for rejecting such messages.

Comment: you are looking for reject_unauth_destination